# Best homemade nutritional babyfood for an infant in the 8 months to 1 year range?

Tags: infant, nutrition, babyfood

Are there some instructions which help in making nutritive homemade baby food for infant in the 8 months to 1 year range? Also such a preparation should ideally be easy to store and feed the infant.

Answer (score 4):

I used to boil a week's worth of various fruits and vegetables (no added salt), puree them individually, set a bit aside for the weekend, pour them in ice cube trays and put them in the freezer. Then we'd take them out as needed every weekday morning and add some oil, put it in a jar to defrost by lunchtime at daycare where they'd warm it up and feed it to the kid. One tray was designated for new kinds of food, so we could follow how much of those he's getting in case of allergic reactions.

We also fed him fresh food, such as spoonfuls of soft avocado or banana, or bits of bread, mashed potatoes, baby cereals, mashed beans, eggs, pureed meat. We were following the pediatrician's suggestions in not adding salt but adding a bit of oil to the veggies. But oil doesn't freeze well, hence the addition only after defrosting.

At that age, we only ever gave him store-bought baby food once, when travelling. He promptly spit it out and then continued to rub his tongue on every surface he could find until it was all gone. Lots of the surface was my shoulder and hair. Never again.

Comment: why no salt and which oil recommended?

Comment: Food contains quite enough salt. Additional salt is bad for such young kidneys. We adults actually eat a quantity of salt that is ridiculously above what we need. Our pediatrician actually said to go easy on the salt even after the first birthday. Specifically, she said: "Now he's ready to eat everything you are... But it's better to use less salt than for yourself. None at all, if possible".

Comment: As for oil, they gave no specific recommendation. It's important that the baby gets some fats, that's all. We would add olive oil.

Comment: One reason to add a few drops of oil is that apparently it helps the body to pick up the vitamins in the food. That's also the reason our juice shop offers to add a bit of oil to the juices they sell.

Comment: Some vitamins are oil-soluble; this is why, for example, whole fat milk is recommended for the first six months to a year (1yr-2yr range), as vitamin D is oil soluble.  Vitamin E is similarly oil soluble, hence the oil-filled caplets.

Comment: Excellent point @user7088 and Joe, I forgot about that.

Comment: do we need to add the oil to the food or can we give it seperately at different time?

Comment: As user7088 and joe pointed out, it's better to give it together with the veggies, because fats help vitamin absorption.

Answer (score 3):

By 8 months to 1 year, we were feeding both of our children what we ate - no difference.  Obviously if you haven't gone through very many foods yet (and thus have allergy concerns), limit this to what you've tried already; we started solids around 4 months so by 8 months had hit all of the high notes there.  What's nutritious for you is also nutritious for the baby.  Make sure the baby is getting enough iron and vitamin D; perhaps consider supplements if you're not sure.  Check with your pediatrician for more information.

If the baby doesn't have teeth, you can use the food processor to partially puree complex foods (say, a lasagna).  Otherwise small pieces should be okay of softer foods.